# How to find the correct color to edit with the Visual Studio 2010 Theme Editor?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, themes, expression-blend

I really like the [Dark Expression theme](http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme) for the [Visual Studio 2010 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378), apart from a few things here and there.

One example is that certain UI elements (such as e.g. Smart Tags) are almost unreadable because they have dark text on dark backgrounds.

I know that I can use the **Customize Colors** dialog(!) box to edit the colors, but how do I figure out which color to edit?

There's *a lot* of colors, and it's not very apparent which ones control which UI elements. Is there any way to figure that out?

Comment: Yeah, *without* resorting to trial and error? This is an excellent question; I've always wondered if this was documented somewhere. +1

Answer (score 2):

you can [snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) Visual Studio to find out more information about the colors used etc. With [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) you can even change the colors and look at the results instantly!

So you can just read out wich color is used on wich place and then search the color by name.

Comment: That's a pretty impressive tool. Alas, I'm now beginning to believe that not all of the colors in VS are settable.